# VSCode Intellisense works when editing a python file but does not work in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using VSCode on a Windows 10 OS. The Intellisense feature works fine when I'm editing a Python file (e.g. when I type 'imp' the editor recommends 'import'), but not when editing a Jupyter notebook within the same VSCode session.

I have tried starting a fresh session, and switching to multiple different interpreters, but the above scenario keeps happening. VSCode's website states that Jupyter Notebook editors have [full IntelliSense support.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support)

*UPDATE*

I disabled and uninstalled a language support extension called Pylance and now the Intellisense works on *some* notebook kernels (e.g. it works in a Python 3.8.0 kernel but not a Python 3.6.5 kernel). Still works just fine in regular *.py files.

Comment: Just double checking, you are opening an ipynb file inside vscode, and not hosting a server using the powershell terminal within vscode, right?

Comment: Correct. Creating a new blank Jupyter notebook, which is then running on the localhost and using local interpreters.

Comment: Might have something to do with the jedi autocompleter. Try disabling it

Comment: I just tried it on my installation of VSCode with a new ipynb and added a new cell, and intellisense started working, but before that it wasn't. That might be the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I disabled and uninstalled 'Pylance' and it started working in SOME Jupyter kernels but not others. See update.

Answer (score 0):

When I use the "`Microsoft`" language service, Jupyter in VS Code has "Intellisense":

[image]

When I use the "`Pylance`" language service, Jupyter in VS Code has "Intellisense":

[image]

As for "Intellisense" in VSCode's website, this problem is currently being fixed.
Github link: [IntelliSense is not working in Jupyter Notebook editor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4505#issuecomment-768575127).

Here is a workaround and you could refer to it:

It is recommended that you use "[Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)", which has rich "Intellisense" in Jupyter:

[image]